# Query from two tables and orderBy date in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables each for its Eloquent . I would like to get results from each of them for specific field (using where clause)

then I want to combine the both resulted array and order them by createdAt date filed

How can I achieve this in laravel5 ? I tried make use of relations but can't make it work

this example of the two arrays separately

```
 $football = Football::where('playerId','=',$id)->get()->toArray();

  $tennis= Tennis::where('playerId','=',$id)->get()->toArray();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming they are on different tables, I can think of 2 solutions:

1)first you have to fetch both results, then you can sort in php using

```
$results = array_merge($football, $tennis);
usort($results, function($a,$b) { 
    return $a['created_at'] < $b['created_at'];
});
```

2) Using raw queries, run a UNION :

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM football WHERE playerId = X
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM tennis WHERE playerId = X
) AS A ORDER BY created_at;
```